# What would be the time complexity of this two nested loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o

given:

```
public void iterate(int n){
    int i =n;
    while (i > 0){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println("*");
            i = i/2;
        }
    }
}
```

I might argue that the time complexity for this operation is linear because comparing `i > 0` would be constant and the for loop inside would be linear. Therefore give a total of `linear time.`

But in my head, i still think the operation is quadratic.

Could anyone please give me a clearer explanation of the complexities on nested loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the outer loop here isn't really doing anything, since `i` is decremented to 0 inside the inner loop. The while loop will only execute one time. The body of the for loop will execute `n` times, so the algorithm is O(n).

If you moved `i = i/2;` to run *after* the for loop body, the while loop would execute log(n) times, so the algorithm would be O(n * log(n)).

Comment: I think that it should be O(log(n)) if I'm not mistaken or n/2.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago Without knowing what "it" is, it's hard to say.

Comment: I mean complexity of algorithm. As you said outer loop is not important. Inner loop is the main part of algorithm which executes n/2 time.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago Thanks for clarifying. The inner loop uses the counter `j`, so it will execute n times. The `i` variable only affects the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

The total cost of the algorithm is O(n).

More specifically, the for loop has n iterations, and each iteration takes a constant amount of time.  (By the way, after log n of these n iterations, i would have reached 0.  For the remaining n - log n iterations, i continues to be equal to 0.  The print statement is executed during each of these n iterations.) So, the total cost of the for loop is O(n).  At the end of these n iterations, i is 0, and so the while loop exits after the first iteration.